# Is there a way for Continuous Integration in Plastic Cloud Version?

Tags: plasticscm

I am using Plastic SCM Cloud Version and was looking into some dev solutions for it. I started out with Jenkins, but it requires a plastic local server and I guess that also applies for Atlassian Bamboo. Is there a way to use merge bots or trunk bots in the cloud edition like in the local version of Plastic? I have already Integrated Jira for task manaement. Also its for Unity as I want to have a streamlined DevOps pipeline with Plastic cloud for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Mergebots are not available for Plastic Cloud at the moment, but you can use the CI integrations plugins if you are using Plastic Cloud. Plastic SCM has plugins for TeamCity, Jenkins and Bamboo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some stuff with some workarounds but not a real CI/CD. As it was mentioned by Carlos that Mergebots are not available for Plastic Cloud. But what you can do is using the "Triggers" option on Plastic Cloud, just like you can set it up to post things on your discord/slack server you can also make it send a POST request to a URL of your choice which would be your own server or a service. After that POST request you will have the data you need on your own server and you can deal with it as you want. You can also play with permissions/rules to disallow certain actions till some other tasks is done.

[Plastic webhook](https://www.plasticscm.com/dashboard/cloud/%5BYOUR_CLOUD%5D/triggers)

[Triggers guide](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/triggers/plastic-scm-version-control-triggers-guide#Security)